# Recursively aggregate SQL columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, aggregate-functions

I have two tables and I'm trying to build a query which would do `JOIN` and a `SUM` of all numerical columns (profit/loss), and then a `SUM` again for all profits, and all losses.

Maybe I've poorly designed my tables - any guidance is appreaciated.

Right now, I have:

Table: **COMPANY**

```
C_ID  |  NAME
-------------------
 1    |  Abc
```

Table: **FINANCIAL**

```
ID  |  COMPANY_ID  |  INCOME1  |  INCOME2  | COST1  |  COST2
------------------------------------------------------------
1          1            200
2          1                        50
3          1                                   5
4          1                                   3
5          1                                             40
```

The output I'm seeking is something like (where CASH has a fixed starting value of 100)

```
C_ID  |  NAME  |  INCOME1  |  INCOME2  | COST1  |  COST2  |  CASH
------------------------------------------------------------------
 1       Abc       200          50         8        40       302
```

What I've tried:

```
SELECT
    C.C_ID, C.NAME,
    SUM(F.INCOME1), SUM(F.INCOME2),
    SUM(F.COST1), SUM(F.COST2),
    (100 +
            (SELECT SUM(F.INCOME1), SUM(F.INCOME2) FROM FINS F)
          - (SELECT SUM(F.COST1), SUM(F.COST2) FROM FINS F)
    )
FROM COMP C
INNER JOIN FINS F
ON C.C_ID = F.COMPANY_ID
GROUP BY C.C_ID, C.NAME
```

Comment: Look up the PIVOT operator in SQL

Comment: Isnt your cash suppose to be `202` after income of `200+50` and cost of `40+8` which is `250 - 48 = 202`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @Company TABLE(C_ID INT,NAME VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @Company VALUES
(1,'Abc')

DECLARE @FINANCIAL TABLE
(ID INT,COMPANY_ID INT,INCOME1 INT,INCOME2 INT,COST1 INT,COST2 INT)
INSERT INTO @FINANCIAL VALUES
(1,1,200,NULL,NULL,NULL),
(2,1,NULL,50 ,NULL,NULL),
(3,1,NULL,NULL,  5,NULL),
(4,1,NULL,NULL,  3,NULL),
(5,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,40)
```

**Query**

```
SELECT *, INCOME1+INCOME2-COST1-COST2 AS CASH
FROM (
SELECT  C.C_ID
       ,C.NAME
       ,SUM(F.INCOME1) AS INCOME1
       ,SUM(F.INCOME2) AS INCOME2
       ,SUM(F.COST1)   AS COST1
       ,SUM(F.COST2)   AS COST2
FROM @Company C INNER JOIN @FINANCIAL F
ON C.C_ID = F.COMPANY_ID
GROUP BY C.C_ID
       ,C.NAME
      ) Q
```

**Result Set**

```
╔══════╦══════╦═════════╦═════════╦═══════╦═══════╦══════╗
║ C_ID ║ NAME ║ INCOME1 ║ INCOME2 ║ COST1 ║ COST2 ║ CASH ║
╠══════╬══════╬═════════╬═════════╬═══════╬═══════╬══════╣
║    1 ║ Abc  ║     200 ║      50 ║     8 ║    40 ║  202 ║
╚══════╩══════╩═════════╩═════════╩═══════╩═══════╩══════╝
```

### [`Working SQL FIDDLE`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/50f8a/1)

Comment: thanks! this worked. There's a starting cash value of 100 which is why it should end up 302.

Comment: Yeah, got that. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```
SELECT C.C_ID, C.NAME, F.INCOME1, F.INCOME2, F.COST1, F.COST2, ((100 + F.INCOME1 + F.INCOME2) - (F.COST1 + F.COST2)) AS CASH
FROM COMPANY C
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT COMPANY_ID, SUM(INCOME1) AS INCOME1, SUM(INCOME2) AS INCOME2
    , SUM(COST1) AS COST1, SUM(COST2) AS COST2
    FROM FINANCIAL
    GROUP BY COMPANY_ID
) F ON C.C_ID = F.COMPANY_ID
```